# Createjs save stage object for later use

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, easeljs, createjs

I'm creating an image editor with createjs and I need to save the current stage state in the database. Later I want to load that same state in the editor. Just like working in photoshop. Editing your image, saving the file and later you want to open the file and continue editing.

Saving the image itself is no problem, but if I load the state of a saved stage object, it doesn't behave or work as a stage object anymore. Only like a regular javascript object.

Normally you would add a createjs stage like this:

```
    var stage = new createjs.Stage();
```

I tried to load an old stage object like this (which is clearly not they way to do it):

```
    var stage = oldStageObject;
```

Does anyone of you know how to load the createjs stage state? 
Links or other useful information is also appreciated, because I couldn't find anything about this in the easeljs stage docs.

Comment: There is no built-in serialization for EaselJS displayObjects. You would have to write one yourself.

Comment: Thank you. Think I'm going to use fabricjs instead.
I would accept your answer, but can only upvote it. Not sure why.